# Алгоритм (формат) хранения данных с быстрыми чтение\запись\и т.п

Tags: c#, алгоритм, хранение-данных

Доброго времени суток.

Цель - подобие редактора электрических схем, реализованного на C#(именно "подобие", т.к. нет полной аналогии).
Для понимания задачи, лучше всего подходит LabView. [img](http://www.ni.com/newsletter/app/largeimage?lang=ru&imageurl=%2Fcms%2Fimages%2Fdevzone%2Fpub%2Fnrjsxmfm912163998723206173.jpg)

Что бы не заниматься копи-пастом, в качестве примера, рассмотрим первый попавшийся подходящий [код](http://www.cyberforum.ru/post7470339.html).
В приведенном коде нас интересует всего лишь способ хранения графических элементов, а именно List< Figure>.

**Вопрос заключается в следующем.**
Какую структуру/алгоритм/формат лучше использовать в замен List< Figure>, чтобы улучшить быстродействие манипуляций над, большим к-вом графических элементов?

При условиях:

Весь контент имеет динамический характер, в процессе добавления\удаления\перемещения элементов:
 - элементы меняют свои размеры
 - элементы могут "наезжать" друг на друга и перекрывать друг друга(Z индекс)
 - рабочее поле меняется в размерах
 - в элементах меняется количество точек подключения
 - линии связи меняют свой маршрут

---

*В предыдущей формулировке вопроса возникли некие разногласия, участки несущие, в какой-то мере, оскорбительный характер и размытость -были вырезаны, остальные моменты рассмотрены ниже.*

---

В прошлый раз я описал теоретическое решение, так как вижу его я, а не как видит профессионал.
`Также рабочее поле условно разделить на блоки, и работать в один момент времени с одним блоком. А если в блоке по прежнему много элементов, использовать бинарный поиск.`

---

> Красивые WPF-шные плюшки жрут память и сразу были отброшены.
>   к примеру http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23871/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part выдал - 1000 элем. = 140мб, 2000 = 178мб
>
> Вам жалко несчастных 200М памяти?...

В одном проекте может насчитываться несколько тысяч элементов.
Линии соединяющие точки элементов - также являются отдельными графическими элементами.
В одном элементе задействованы, как минимум, две точки.
Бывают элементы с задействованными 20-30-50(и более) точками.
Десятки тысяч вполне реальные цифры(а то и сотни)

---

> Если дерево поиска для вас сложная структура...
>
> К сожалению моя профессия не имеет никакого отношения к программированию, всего лишь хобби.
>   Мои познания во всех направлениях имеют поверхностный характер.
>   С деревьями знаком слабо, отложил в сторонку, пока не появиться больше свободного времени для изучения.

В большей степени не сложная структура, а сложность ее применения в данной постановке.

Далее моя не "прогерская" логика говорит

> А еще мы не учли магические сочетания "Ctrl+A", "Ctrl+С" и "Ctrl+V", которые сведут на "0" все наши преимущества.

При перемещении\удалении\добавлении большого количества элементов, придется перестраивать\пересоздавать дерево. *Этот момент и вызывает спорные ощущения.*
Я не достаточно осведомлен в научных терминах, мне как говорится "Лучше раз увидеть, чем сто раз услышать".
Потому и просил реальный пример, мне на примере легче освоится ежели разбираться в терминах.

Comment: Вам бы книги писать)) Ваш вопрос слишком размыто стоит, аудитории не понятно что вы хотите хранить в структуре данных, какой тип, какие примерные обьемы и т.д. сформулируйте вопрос четче.

Comment: Вам жалко несчастных 200М памяти? Тогда вы сами себе злобный буратино.

Comment: Высоким требованиям сложная реализация. Посмотрите на базы данных, например. В них обычно есть сам датасет и индексы по нему в форме мапов различных видов: хэшмапов, самобалансирующихся деревьев. Данные дублируются по ссылкам, чем больше индексов, тем выше цена их поддержания на операциях записи. А вопрос слишком неконкретен и подлежит закрытию.

Comment: "D-side"  - Согласен, вопрос задан в необычном стиле. Обновил пост, задача намного проще.

Comment: "обратится к элементу находящемуся под курсором без перебора всех элементов в массиве(листе)" -- похоже на стандартный кейс банального дерева поиска. "Tree map". Будучи сбалансированным, представляет собой практически отсортированный массив, где каждая операция чтения это бинарный поиск. Вы вообще на каком уровне знаете структуры данных? Какая самая сложная вам известна?

Comment: "D-side" - к сожалению моя профессия не имеет никакого отношения к программированию. Программирование для меня всего лишь хобби. Так что мои познания во всех направлениях имеют поверхностный характер. С деревьями знаком слабо и изза сложности их реализации, отложил в сторонку, пока не появиться больше свободного времени для изучения.

Comment: Вот в ядре и надо экономить память. А графические приложения экономить не должны, иначе у вас и будут самописные велосипеды без свойств. // По сути вопроса — думаю. вам нужен `SortedSet`. Впрочем, на количестве элементов порядка сотни и линейный поиск в массиве достаточно быстр. // Вы совершаете типичную ошибку новичка: преждевременную оптимизацию. Сначала реализуйте вашу проект, потом найдите узкое место, и оптимизируйте его. Из моего опыта, обычно узкое место находится совсем не в том месте, где предполагает программист.

Comment: @VladD вот да, я прямо сейчас могу сказать, что организация отрисовки схемы - это даже не вершина айсберга, а так, наледь после оттепели. Я делал нечто подобное, но не по электрике, а по вакуумным системам. Основные проблемы будут в создании модели для рассчетов и самих расчетов и еще какие проблемы, если замахнуться на 2к элементов и больше. А если без расчетов - так просто схемы рисовать может тот же Visio, даже библиотеки элементов есть.

Comment: Если дерево поиска для вас сложная структура, а амбиции по структурам данных на такой высоте, вам надо для начала поднять общую осведомлённость по этой теме. Почитать про разные реализации деревьев поиска, к примеру, [тут](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85). Представление о "сложны в реализации" рискует улететь куда-то в бетонный пол от вида **действительно** сложных структур :)

Comment: "VladD" - согласен, но частично. В посте кусок реальной схемы, сколько элементов можете насчитать? При неправильном подходе, целая схема будет занимать Гиг-йты, хотя реальный вес в десятки раз меньше.
D-side - У меня поверхностные знания, а не отсутствуют совсем. Я имел ввиду 
что в конкретно моем случае будет сложно реализовать, а с учетом большого количества динамического контента, выигрыш от дерева будет спорным. А Вы меня как школьника вики читать. Лучше бы конкретный пример, мне на примере легче освоится.

Comment: Спорным? Снизить сложность чтения по условию с O(N) до о O(log N)? Видимо, вам всё же надо в вики.

Comment: В вашем вопросе нет, собственно, самого вопроса. По сути вы наткнулись на стандарную проблему индексации данных. Магического решения нет - или вы получаете O(N) при поиске по объектам, или O(log n) при поиске + накладные расходы при изменении. Да, это стандартная дилемма - например, она возникает при подборе индексов в любой реляционной базы данных. И у нее есть стадартное решение - попробовать на реальных данных и поменять. По результатам измерений выбрать подходящий вариант.

Comment: Кстати, ваша логика, которая говорит что "Ctrl+C" сведет на нет выигрыш от индексов - ошибочна. Есть вполне быстрые алгоритмы мержа деревьев. Ну и к тому же, десятки тысяч - это смешные объемы для современного железа с миллиардами операций в секунду.